# Word wrapping in tabulary not working with multicolumns

Tags: tables, multicolumn, tabulary

Why does this table overfull when I use multicolumns for the header? Without multicolumns the third column lines are wrapping, but not with multicolumns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:models} Models of channel-independent perturbations under comparison.}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{lcL}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Model} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Abbreviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Assumptions}\\
%Model & Abbreviation & Assumptions\\
\hline
Weighted mean & WM & $\Delta(r) = 0$\\
Micke-Mayer method & MM & $f(\Delta)$ uniform distribution, $\sigma_{k}$ are equal\\
Uniform distribution & UD & $f(\Delta)$ uniform distribution\\
Truncated normal distribution & TD & $f(\Delta)$ truncated normal distribution\\
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a feature of the package.

this works though

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:models} Models of channel-independent perturbations under comparison.}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{lcL}
Model & Abbreviation &\centering Assumptions\tabularnewline
%Model & Abbreviation & Assumptions\\
\hline
Weighted mean & WM & $\Delta(r) = 0$\\
Micke-Mayer method & MM & $f(\Delta)$ uniform distribution, $\sigma_{k}$ are equal\\
Uniform distribution & UD & $f(\Delta)$ uniform distribution\\
Truncated normal distribution & TD & $f(\Delta)$ truncated normal distribution\\
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```